# Tensorflow tf.saved_model not keeping model loaded in memory, have to re-load in loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, video

I am using a Tensorflow vision library which works fine 1 image at a time, and I am trying to extend it to run within a loop looking at every frame of a video.

It works for the first frame (first loop iteration) then stops detecting. However, it works if I call `tf.saved_model.load(...)` every loop iteration, but this is extremely slow and I would think unneeded.

Code outline below. I am running `infer` on frames of a video one at a time. `Infer` seems to work fine on a single image when it's run alone by itself in a script. But when I put it in this loop, it only works for frame 1, then afterwards it does nothing. Unless I manually call `saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load` again inside the loop. Then it works but is incredibly slow.

```
saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(FLAGS.weights, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
print("saved_model_loaded :: "); print(saved_model_loaded)
infer = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']

video_file = ...
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read() # works fine
    frame_count = frame_count + 1
    print("frame_count :: "+str(frame_count))

    # saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(FLAGS.weights, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
    # print("saved_model_loaded :: "); print(saved_model_loaded)
    # ^ I can uncomment the above and analysis will work every iteration..

    infer = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']

    # print("infer obj :: "); print(infer)
    batch_data = tf.constant(images_data)
    pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)
    for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
        boxes = value[:, :, 0:4]
        pred_conf = value[:, :, 4:]

    # ...

    image = utils.draw_bbox(original_image, pred_bbox, FLAGS.info, allowed_classes=allowed_classes)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow('image',image) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any ideas why `infer` doesn't work unless I call `saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(..)` in the loop right before it again? I would think the model just gets loaded once into my RAM and then can keep predicting.

Some print statement debug output in case it's relevant:

```
saved_model_loaded ::
<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x000002A5D346E278>
frame_count :: 1
saved_model_loaded ::
<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x000002A5D346E278>
infer obj ::
<ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(input_1) at 0x2A5BB63DE80>
(99, 174)
Objects detected
frame_count :: 2
saved_model_loaded ::
<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x000002A5D346E278>
infer obj ::
<ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(input_1) at 0x2A5BB63DE80>
frame_count :: 3
saved_model_loaded ::
<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x000002A5D346E278>
infer obj ::
<ConcreteFunction signature_wrapper(input_1) at 0x2A5BB63DE80>
frame_count :: 4
saved_model_loaded ::
<tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject object at 0x000002A5D346E278>
```

Only frame 1 detects anything. But again if I put `tf.saved_model.load(..)` in loop, it will detect every frame, at the cost of re-loading and taking forever. What can I try next?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.